# "docker run" command to evaluate bash $variable inside the container

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, containers

How can I run a command inside a docker container, using `docker run`, where bash variables are evaluated *inside* the container?

E.g.:

```
$ SOMEONE=host
$ docker run --env SOMEONE=busybox busybox echo "Hello $SOMEONE"
Hello host
```

How can I make it output `Hello busybox`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- To prevent the replacement from happening from the outer shell, one needs to use single quotes, not double.
- To ensure that there *is* an inner shell that *can* do a replacement (`echo` doesn't have any such functionality itself!), we need to explicitly call `sh -c`; otherwise, Docker will just directly invoke `execlp("echo", "echo", "$SOMEONE", NUL)` inside the container, which doesn't actually do any substitution.

---

Thus:

```
docker run --env SOMEONE=busybox busybox sh -c 'echo "Hello $SOMEONE"'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using docker run, where bash variables are evaluated inside

By far the easiest, non-cryptic approach is to write a bash function with all commands to be executed inside the container. Benefits:

- Easy to write - no need to use special quote placement and escaping
- Easy to debug - see what bash actually does inside the container
- Easy to maintain - write readable scripts, not cryptic commands

**Easy to write and maintain**

Here's an example bash function that expands all variables inside a docker container.

```
-- (host) $ ./create-db.sh
#!/bin/bash

function main_inside_docker {
  # all variables are expanded insider docker
  DBNAME=${1:-testdb}
  echo "creating database $DBNAME"
  PATH=$MSSQL_PATH:$PATH
  SQL="
  create database $DBNAME;
  select database_id, name, create_date from sys.databases;
  "
  sqlcmd -U SA -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "$SQL"
}

# declare the function inside docker and run it there
CMD="$(declare -f main_inside_docker); main_inside_docker $@"
docker exec -it mssql bash -c "$CMD"
```

Essentially this declares the `main_inside_docker` function inside the container, then runs it with all arguments provided from the host invocation. All variables inside the function are expanded inside the docker container. The function just works the way one would expect.

**Easy to debug**

To debug the function, set "-x" as the first command in `$CMD`:

```
CMD="set -x; $(declare -f ...)"
```

When running it this way, it will print the bash trace from inside the container nicely:

```
(host) $ ./create-db.sh foodb
+ main_inside_docker
+ DBNAME=foodb
+ echo 'creating database foodb'
creating database testdb
...
```

Comment: This is great practice _until_ you get to the assignment of `CMD`, where you have `$@` unquoted and thus getting replaced with the parent process's arguments after they're squashed together into a single space-separated string.

Comment: Consider `printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$@"`, and then substituting `$cmd_q` into your string.

Comment: (if you need some examples of how the original code can cause incorrect behavior, let me know; I'd be glad to build a reproducer for some concrete bugs).

Comment: This one's more like a quibble, btw, but also think about using lower-case names for your own variables; all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to POSIX-specified tools, whereas those tools -- including the shell -- are required to ignore variables with at least one lowercase character in their name as "reserved for applications". See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html for the relevant naming convention -- search for "The name space of" -- keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable.